# do I have to register each device token that download my app ?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

I am using apple notification service, so in this function do I have to register each device token that download my app or in other word when I want to send the notification , to what address i have to send it .

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]];
NSLog(@"%@",str);}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use a service such as Urban Airship.  You would create a database (probably MySQL) then use a language such as PHP to create a file that would allow you to POST the device token and then put that into the database.

In PHP this would look like

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$connection){
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("my_database", $connection);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tokens (token)
VALUES ('$_POST[token]')");

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

On the iOS Side you would use the following code:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString *urlString;
    NSURL *url;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request;
    NSString *postString;

    urlString = @"http://yoururl.com/apns/registerDevice";
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"token=%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    (void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    //Casting this to void makes the warning of unused expression go away.
}
```

Comment: PLEASE make sure that you sanitise your inputs before inserting them into the database!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should get every device token, however if you want to keep it simple, I strongly suggest you use Urban Airship for your push notifications.

Comment: is it free please ?

and how to save each device token ?

Comment: There is a free basic plan. They are keeping the device tokens in their own database. Like I said this is good if you want to keep it simple, else you can implement your own database and send the push notif. Your self.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit late but careful, **NEVER** put a

```
$_POST['ivar']
```

in a SQL Query string, it's the better way to get in touch with SQL Injection ! Please use prepare query